# UNity3D error displaying variable from another script c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got a UI Text element (inside a canvas) that I need to grab a value from another script.

The way I'm doing right now (and that was the closest I got to get it working) is:

```
public class AttributeValueController : MonoBehaviour {

//public AttributeName attribute;
[SerializeField]
private Text attributeValue = null;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    attributeValue.text = CharacterGenerator._toon.GetPrimaryAttribute("Might").AdjustedBaseValue.ToString();   
}
```

I got the text component I want to be changed set on on the inspector to the "attributeValue".

When I run this I get the errors

> Assets/Scripts/HUD Classes/AttributeValueController.cs(19,58): error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `CharacterGenerator._toon'

and

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   UnityEngine.UI.Graphic.OnRebuildRequested () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Graphic.cs:480)
>   UnityEngine.UI.GraphicRebuildTracker.OnRebuildRequested () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/GraphicRebuildTracker.cs:33)
>   UnityEngine.CanvasRenderer.RequestRefresh () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/modules/UI/CanvasRendererBindings.gen.cs:314)

Anyone can help? When I replace this function by "0" it works... I've searched everywhere and I cannot fix it

Comment: never use "[SerializeField]" for any reason.  delete that!

Comment: it;'s absolutely impossible to help you unless you include ***ALL*** of BOTH classes of the components in question.  ALL of the classes, including the top lines and so on.

Answer (score -1):

If `CharacterGenerator` isn't a static class, you can't access it like that. You would have to make an instance of the class to access properties.

```
CharacterGenerator cGen = new CharacterGenerator();
attributeValue.text = cGen._toon.GetPrimaryAttribute("Might").AdjustedBaseValue.ToString();
```

Although, given this is a new instance of the class, I would not expect these properties to be populated, but perhaps your class is structured so that they are.

Comment: Given that he received the exception 'An object reference is required to access non-static member `CharacterGenerator._toon'', I'm sure it's different, but I highly doubt that error means something other than what it means... Did you read the OP?

Comment: Anyway, Unity or not, the rules still apply. He's trying to access something statically that is not static. You can't do that in C#.

Comment: Also @JoeBlow, `CharacterGenerator` is not a pre-defined class of Unity... So I'm not sure what you're talking about here. Might want to correct what you've said as it is most certainly misleading.

Comment: I see what you mean I think, he may not even be assigning the `.Text` value properly, but he's also not accessing the property he wants to put into there properly.